# Settings global conditional variables in Go

Tags: variables, go, conditional-statements

I want to parse and set a variable conditionally in Go at the global package level based on the value of of an ENV var, so that I don't have to check for it every time in a utility function (as the variable would be declared once at run time). For example, what I want to accomplish is (Go pseudo-code):

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

// This works to read the value of MYVAR (=true/false)
var myvar string = os.Getenv("MYVAR")

// Apparently this is too much for Go
var myvarbool, _ = strconv.ParseBool(myvar)

// Utility function to check for value
func mycheck() {
    if myvarbool {
        fmt.Print("MYVAR is true")
    }
}
```

This is a library package, so doesn't have a main() function to do this kind of setup, but I want to be able to use mycheck() in other functions in the library, and don't want to have to read and parse MYVAR every time mycheck() is called.

Comment: The socalled 'init' functions exist to do this kind of initialization of package-level state: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#init

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what problem you had, your code from the OP is valid, also you can have it in one line like:

```
var myvarbool, _ = strconv.ParseBool(os.Getenv("MYVAR"))
```

<kbd>[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/Fi_i1s_X8U)</kbd>

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea what the problem was; I've re-tried this as a simple test case, and it works perfectly. Before Go was chucking an error about assignment, but I can't recreate it.

Answer (score 6):

One way to accomplish what you're looking to do would be to process the environment variable in an init() function, so something like the following would work:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

var (
    myvar string = os.Getenv("MYVAR")
    myvarbool bool
)

func init() {
    myvarbool, _ = strconv.ParseBool(myvar)
}

// Utility function to check for value
func mycheck() {
    if myvarbool {
        fmt.Print("MYVAR is true")
    }
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/2NA1_vR2OM)

Comment: Ignoring `err` is not going to end well.  Maybe panic if `err != nil`?

Comment: My apologies, I should have stated that this is not code I would willingly commit to my own repos - it was simply a slightly more idiomatic manner to solve this problem (offloading _initialization_ code to all run in `func init() { ...} ` so that we are setup to go before we hit main).

Comment: Fair enough.  I guess I would tend to only have `myvarbool` in the global namespace, and to call `os.Getenv("whatever")` directly in init.

Comment: @SamMussmann while ignoring errors is generally bad, for that specific instance it's not important at all, it's a bool value.

Answer (score 0):

After actually thinking about this for a couple of minutes, I've realised I can just create a wrapper function to do the work, and call that instead (again, largely pseudo-code without extra checks):

```
var myenvbool bool = myenv("MYVAR")

func myenv(envvar string) bool {
    myenvvalue := os.Getenv(envvar)
    myenvbool, _ := strconv.ParseBool(myenvvalue)
    return myenvbool
}

func checkenv() {
    if myenvbool {
        fmt.Print("myenvbool is true")
    }
}
```